# Remove first "." from values in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a dataset with different values in R. Some values are like 11.474 and others like 1.034.496 in the same column. I would like to change the values with two dots from 1.034.496 to 1034.496. Is there anyone who could help me please?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suggest you can use `str_replace(df$column, ".", "")` from `library(stringr)`

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez, the `"."` matches *any character*, did you instead mean to escape it, as in `str_replace(df$column, "\\.", "")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub` with Perl regexes:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('11.474', '1.034.496', '1.234.034.496'))
df$a = gsub('[.](?=.*[.])', '', df$a, perl = TRUE)
print(df)
##             a
## 1      11.474
## 2    1034.496
## 3 1234034.496
```

Here, `[.](?=.*[.])` is a literal dot (has to be escaped like so `\.` or put into a character class like so: `[.]`), followed by a literal dot using positive lookahead: `(?=PATTERN)`.

Comment: Nice work, its a concise solution with pattern `[.](?=.*[.])` in `gsub`, voted for yours!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there must be other smarter `regex` approaches than the below one, but here is my attempt

```
> ifelse(lengths(gregexpr("\\.",v))>1,sub("\\.","",v),v)
[1] "11.474"   "1034.496"
```

where

```
v <- c("11.474","1.034.496")
```